# How do I clearInterval(interval) from outside the function it's in?

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

There is an onclick function that invokes count(), timeDisplay() and reset().

I want to clearInterval(interval) from inside reset(). I simply just want to make clicks=0, seconds =20, and have the interval stop when reset() is invoked.

```
var clicks=0;
var seconds=20;
var clicked=false;
var msg="";
function clickDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=
    clicks;
}
function timeDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=
    seconds;
}
function count(){
    clicks++;
    clickDisplay();
}
function timerFunction(){
    if(!clicked){
        clicked=true;
        var interval=setInterval(function(){
            seconds--;
            timeDisplay();
            if(seconds==0){
                clearInterval(interval);
                msg="You clicked the button "+
                clicks+
                " times!"+
                "\r\n"+
                "You clicked the button "+
                clicks/20
                +" times per second!";
                alert(msg);
            }
        },1000);
    }
}
function reset(){
    clicked=false;
    clicks=0;
    seconds=20;
    clickDisplay();
    timeDisplay();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the `interval` variable outside of `timerFunction`, so that all other functions can have access to it (which includes `reset()`):

```
// Store interval outside
var interval;

var clicks=0;
var seconds=20;
var clicked=false;
var msg="";
function clickDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML=
    clicks;
}
function timeDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=
    seconds;
}
function count(){
    clicks++;
    clickDisplay();
}
function timerFunction(){
    if(!clicked){
        clicked=true;
        interval=setInterval(function(){
            seconds--;
            timeDisplay();
            if(seconds==0){
                clearInterval(interval);
                msg="You clicked the button "+
                clicks+
                " times!"+
                "\r\n"+
                "You clicked the button "+
                clicks/20
                +" times per second!";
                alert(msg);
            }
        },1000);
    }
}
function reset(){
    clearInterval(interval);

    clicked=false;
    clicks=0;
    seconds=20;
    clickDisplay();
    timeDisplay();  
}
```

Comment: This did not work. I feel like it's my fault though and you know what you're talking about. The only changes you made were you put `var interval;` at the top and put `clearInterval(interval);` inside `reset()`...right?